# How to replace old graph from Matplotlib with a new one - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, user-interface, tkinter

Good evening,

I have written a function which creates a matplotlib graph from a dataset called "datenplot". Each time I call the function through a button in my TKinter GUI a new plot is added under the previous one. I would like to have the old plot replaced by a new one as soon as I call the function from my button, but I am too incompetent for that at the moment.

This is the Code:

```
def grafik(uebergebene_daten):
    datenplot = uebergebene_daten

    fig = Figure(figsize=(10, 4), dpi=100)

    fig.add_subplot(111).plot((datenplot[1]), (datenplot[0]))

    canvas1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = root)
    canvas1.draw()
    canvas1.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.NONE, expand=0)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Greetings and thanks!

PS: I am new here and this is my first question, I am still a beginner in programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest way might be to destroy the canvas itself using `canvas1.get_tk_widget().destroy()` also note that using `time.sleep()` might make your GUI unresponsive so I suggest you use `after()` method provided by tkinter.

Here is an example:

```
from tkinter import *
from matplotlib.figure import Figure 
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, 
NavigationToolbar2Tk)

def grafik(uebergebene_daten=(10, 10, 10, 10)):
    global canvas1

    if canvas1:
        canvas1.get_tk_widget().destroy()
    
    datenplot = uebergebene_daten

    fig = Figure(figsize=(10, 4), dpi=100)
    plot1 = fig.add_subplot(111) 

    canvas1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = window)
    canvas1.draw()
    canvas1.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=NONE, expand=0)
    window.after(1000, None)


window = Tk() 

canvas1 = None

# setting the title 
window.title('Plotting in Tkinter') 

# dimensions of the main window 
window.geometry("700x700") 


# button that displays the plot 
plot_button = Button(master = window, command = grafik, height = 2, width = 10, text = "Plot") 
# place the button 
plot_button.pack() 

# run the gui 
window.mainloop()
```